# (VBA) Late Binding (avaoid reference) of Acrobat Type Library

Tags: vba, pdf, reference, acrobat, late-binding

Is it possible to avoid the reference to the Adobe Acrobat Type Library somehow?
I cannot figure it out how...I receive an ActiveX error message.

I only paste an extract of my code as the rest is not that important.
Here is the code with early binding (set up reference):

```
Dim Fol_Path As String
Dim Each_Page As Boolean

Dim AC_PD As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim AC_Hi As Acrobat.AcroHiliteList
Dim AC_PG As Acrobat.AcroPDPage
Dim AC_PGTxt As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect

Dim OS_FSO As Object
Dim OS_TxtFile As Object

Set OS_FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")

Dim Ct_Page As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim T_Str As String

Dim Hld_Txt As Variant

Each_Page = True

Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Set AC_Hi = New Acrobat.AcroHiliteList
AC_Hi.Add 0, 32767
```

...
...
...

```
        Set AC_PG = .AcquirePage(i - 1)

        Set AC_PGTxt = AC_PG.CreateWordHilite(AC_Hi)
```

Comment: Declare `as object` forces late binding (aka IDispatch). Then Create the object with `set x = CreateObject(objectname)` (for an app object) or `set x = GetObject(filename)` (for a document object).

Comment: Using late binding you can do things like create a document object for each file in a folder and send command `PrintOut` to it. If the app can print it will (else you'll get an error you can ignore).

Comment: in the first sub I managed to do late binding, this sub splits a PDF file into pieces (each page a file). but with this sub I have problems, this sub opens those splitted PDF files and read out the whole content and saves it into a string variable.
Thanks @ACatInLove: I will try that, but what is IDispatch specifically?

Comment: The interface that is Late Binding. It goes Client Program: *Hello sever do you have a command called PrintOut*. Server: *Yes I do, command number 8*. Client Program: *Please do command number 8* . Server: *Sure, here's the result* . In early binding your program knows to just look up command number 8. It's the eighth function address in the VTable. Plus your compiler knows what the function expects and won't compile till you get it right. In late binding YOU need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ACatinLove
thanks! It worked! (my code extract as the result).
Somewhere I read that one should put "Const AcroExch As Long = 0" after Dim, why is so?

```
Dim AC_PD As Object
Dim AC_Hi As Object
Dim AC_PG As Object
Dim AC_PGTxt As Object

'Const AcroExch As Long = 0

Dim OS_FSO As Object
Dim OS_TxtFile As Object

Set OS_FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")

Dim Ct_Page As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim T_Str As String

Dim Hld_Txt As Variant

Each_Page = True

'Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
'Set AC_Hi = New Acrobat.AcroHiliteList

Set AC_PD = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set AC_Hi = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")
```